# grouping rows of common values to create a new 'group id' for each set

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to achieve the below but was not able to so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have this data (sorted from a query by id, anchor, date, and time) that I wish to group by common anchor :

```
id anchor date        time     'group' (the value to get)
3  2      2019-01-01  07:00     1
4  2      2019-01-01  08:00     1
5  3      2019-01-01  15:00     2
7  3      2019-01-01  16:00     2
10 3      2019-01-01  17:00     2
```

I'm looking to do a query in postgres where I can select this data and foreach set of common anchors, have a 'group number'
I then need a query to sum the anchor of points of same group, example above would become:

```
anchor sum group
2      4   1
3      9   2
```

thanks!

EDIT: McNets solution works perfect,
I have another case, with below data.
The anchor repeats but after a change of anchor: they're sorted by time, first it was anchor 2, then anchor 3, then again anchor 2.
I need to group after the change (ids 11 & 12) to have a new group number in this case

```
id anchor date        time     'group' (the value to get)
3  2      2019-01-01  07:00     1
4  2      2019-01-01  08:00     1
5  3      2019-01-01  15:00     2
7  3      2019-01-01  16:00     2
10 3      2019-01-01  17:00     2
11 2      2019-01-01  18:00     3
12 2      2019-01-01  19:00     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DENSE_RANK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function:

```
select
    anchor, sum(anchor) as "sum", grp  as "group"
from
    (select 
         anchor, dense_rank() over (order by anchor) as grp
     from
         t) t1
group by
    anchor, grp
order by
    grp;
```

> ```
> anchor | sum | group
> -----: | --: | ----:
>      2 |   4 |     1
>      3 |   9 |     2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=064efb772091d184dfc1cf893fdd2058)*

More examples about DENSE_RANK [here.](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-dense_rank-function/)

Even though it is preferable to add a new question when there is a significant change, this is the answer at your edited question.

```
select anchor,
       sum(anchor) as "sum",
       grp as "group"
from (
      select anchor, dt, tm,
             sum(rst) over (order by dt, tm) as grp
      from (
            select anchor, dt, tm,
                   case when coalesce(lag(anchor) 
                                      over (order by dt, tm), 0) <> anchor 
                        then 1 end as rst
            from   t
           ) t1
     ) t2
group by anchor, grp
order by grp;
```

> ```
> anchor | sum | group
> -----: | --: | ----:
>      2 |   4 |     1
>      3 |   9 |     2
>      2 |   4 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=beba999bb49be63bc0f86cd3014c7667)*

Comment: ah perfect!  thanks...another tricky matter came up, i put it as an edit, would love to hear your thoughts on that...boggled my mind for a while

Comment: thanks a lot, did the job perfectly..did some modifications, but was able to undertand the logic...some new stuff to me here xD